# Image Segmentation tiff files for Object Detection

Tags: labeling, geotiff-tiff, pixel, image-segmentation

I have tiff files generated fro 12 bands of sentinel-2a data. I want to label each pixel of the tiff files as belonging to copper mine or normal.

After labelling I want the image format to stay as it is, with only labels for each pixel.

Is there any free tool to do this?

I have been trying on AWS, but it doesn't seem to work on tiff files.

EDIT : It would be helpful if it can be done through scikit-learn or through Python libraries.

Answer (score -1):

use tensorflow for object detection